# Problem with getList() in ngx-restangular

Tags: angular, restangular

I'm using Angular 8.2.0 and ngx-restangular on it. In my service I use `getList()`; the following error appears in the console
`Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else.`

I researched and looked at Restangular's methods. I tried to output with `get()` instead of `getList()` but it didn't work.

```
getAllBalanceListIssues(context: string, month: string): Observable<SusaList[]> {
    let url = `/susa?context=${context}`;
    if (month !== null) {
      url = `${url}&period=${month}`;
    }
    return this.restAngular.all(url).getList();
}
```

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else
    at SafeSubscriber.okCallback [as _next] (ngx-restangular.js:1363)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at CatchSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at CatchSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been always like this and this is the normal behavior. The getList method expects an array as its result. instead if you want to call an API which returns back an object (with or without pagination) you must use the get method and then map the result into your desired model class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your return type of list if it is JSON object then only it is accepted otherwise restangular not accept another type of response only accepts JSON object.